# About the acidity of Sultiame

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, everyday-chemistry, drugs

[image]

Why is sulthiam base even hough sulfur can accept the electron by resonance from nitrogen
like carbonyl group do?

Comment: Aniline is still basic. It's only that it's basicity is reduced due to resonance effects. Same applies here.

Comment: Amides are not usually considered as base though.

Comment: So, you're asking about acidity, or basicity? Both are pretty weak in sulphonamides.